# C# Cannot delete folder contains PDF or DOC files

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-10

I have an issue that has just happened yesterday. Before, I use `Directory.Delete(path, true)` to delete all files and subfolders and it worked correctly.

But now, when I run my program run to this method, if the folder contains PDF or DOC files, these files cannot be deleted and even the EXE file of my program is deleted. It is so weird.

If the folder only contains text file such as TXT or CSV, these files can be deleted.

Now all of my old programs that I did not changed anything for a long time also have this issue.

If the folder has less than 2 documents, these files can be deleted. If more than that, it does not work.

Could you please help me with this issue and let me know how I can fix it ?

Thanks,

Tu.

Comment: The files are probably in use by something.  What error do you get?

Comment: Your updated antivirus' heuristics is triggered by mass-deleting user documents, and your program is moved to quarantine?

Comment: Is Directory.Delete throwing an exception?  if so, what is the exception?

Comment: There is no error, when debugging, the debug is stopped and the .exe file also is deleted. I tried to create a simple console application with one line code: Directory.Delete(@"C:\aaa") but no hope :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like it could be your anti-virus attempting to "protect" you. Sometimes an anti-virus will kill and move an application to the quarantine folder if the application is trying to delete a bunch of user files. If you are running anti-virus check the quarantine folder.

Another possibility is that your .exe file is in the folder you are trying to delete.

These are just guesses at what the problem might be. If you are able to post the code you are running we would be more likely to be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is like what you said. My antivirus program consider my program is a virus when it deletes multiple documents and it move my application to the quarantine folder.

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad I was able to help you